# Cognito User Pool direct link to SIGNUP endpoint in Auth API

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a signup and signin flow using the API Auth endpoints provided by Cognito. I am using the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint, which forwards the user to the `/login` endpoint. On the bottom of the resulting Hosted UI page there is a link to the `/signup` endpoint.

I would like to provide my users with a direct link to the `/signup` endpoint, so that they can directly sign up without having to pass through the login screen. I can however not find this endpoint documented where the other endpoints are documented ([User Pool Auth API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html))

**Q1**: Is the `/signup` endpoint documented anywhere in the Cognito documentation?

**Q2**: Is it considered acceptable practice to directly link to the `/signup` endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

Q1: In the end it's using the Sign AP API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html

Q2: The issue with this is, how would your client now if the user is already signed up? Do you want to redirect the user to sign up even if he is registered already?

One option i consider for building a 'non-standard' login/signup workflow is just building you own login/signup pages/frontend or integrate it into you web application. In the background use the Cognito API directly.

Comment: I would like to show my users both a sign up and a sign in button, so that they can click on the appropriate one. For this I would like to use the hosted UI, but I am reluctant to directly use the `/signup` endpoint since I can't find it documented.